# Undefined refence to 'vtable for Adafruit_GFX' due cross compiling raspberry pi

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, raspberry-pi

In Visualstudio by trying to cross compile to a raspberry pi, I get the following error:

> VisualGDB: Run "make CONFIG=Debug" in directory "/tmp/VisualGDB/c/Users/Revius/Desktop/usbtest/conversiecsc++/LinuxProject12/LinuxProject12" on pi@raspberrypi (SSH)
>
> g++ -ggdb -ffunction-sections -O0   -DDEBUG  -c LinuxProject12.cpp -o Debug/LinuxProject12.o -MD -MF Debug/LinuxProject12.dep
>
> g++ -o Debug/LinuxProject12 -Wl,-gc-sections   -L/home/pi/libssd1306/build/ArduiPi_OLED -Wl,--start-group Debug/LinuxProject12.o   -Wl,--rpath='$ORIGIN'   -Wl,--end-group
> Debug/LinuxProject12.o: In function `Adafruit_GFX::~Adafruit_GFX()':
>
> C:\Users\Revius\AppData\Local\VisualGDB\RemoteSourceCache\raspberrypi\0003\include\Adafruit_GFX.h(35): error VGDB1000: undefined reference to `vtable for Adafruit_GFX'

The part off Adafruit_GFX.H where the compiler is pointing to is

```
    "virtual ~Adafruit_GFX() {};"
```

in:

```
    #ifndef _ADAFRUIT_GFX_H
    #define _ADAFRUIT_GFX_H

    #define swap(a, b) { int16_t t = a; a = b; b = t; }

    //class Adafruit_GFX : public Print {
    class Adafruit_GFX {
    public:

    //Adafruit_GFX();
    // i have no idea why we have to formally call the constructor. kinda sux
    void constructor(int16_t w, int16_t h);
    virtual ~Adafruit_GFX() {};
    // this must be defined by the subclass
    virtual void drawPixel(int16_t x, int16_t y, uint16_t color) = 0;
    virtual void invertDisplay(boolean i);
```

The weird part is that I use "make" on the raspberry pi and in works, I can start so it works the code is alright? But not by Visualstudio?

So my question is:
Due I am cross compilling could i be the compiler is missing some file or are there options i could manipulate to get it working?

In which direction do I have to look to find the answer?

Comment: Have you provided a definition in the base class for `invertDisplay`?

Comment: Yes, it is. However the part of code you see here is much bigger so there could be more definitions not used. But the code works on a raspberry pi. They use the same "cross compiler". Could there be some settings to adjust?

Answer (score 0):

[Setting for the Makefile in MSVS-GDB for oled display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH18a.png)

By adjusting (or correct filling in te settings) i got it working.